# Find all Polynomials like $p(x)$ such that $x\ p(x+1) = p(x+2)$

Tags: polynomials

Find all polynomials $p(x)$ with real coefficients and $x\ p(x+1) = p(x+2)$.

So if we substitute $x = 0$ we get $p(2) = 0$.

If we substitute $x = 1$ we get $p(3) = 0$ and if we continue we can say for $n > 1 : p(n) = 0$.

But what about $n \leq 1$?

Comment: *How* do we get $p(3)=0$ if we substitute $x=1$?

Comment: Recall that a polynomial of degre $n$ has at most $n$ roots.

Comment: Something is off. The constant $p(x)=0$ is the only solution. For otherwise the polynomial on the left has a higher degree than the one on the right.

Comment: For the "correct" version the techniques from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/482354/11619) and/or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/515827/11619) will possibly help.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen exactly

Comment: My previous comment meant: you proved that $p$ has infinitely many roots. Hence it cannot have a degree $n\in\Bbb Z_{\ge0}$. Therefore, $p=0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could prove by induction that $p(n)=0$ for all $n\ge2$: the base case is $p(2)=0p(1)$; if $p(n)=0$, then $p(n+1)=p(n)(n-1)=0$. Then use the well-know result that a polynomial with infinitely many roots must be $0$.

A simpler approach is to observe that $p(x+2)$ and $p(x+1)$ have the same degree, therefore if $p\ne 0$ then $\deg(p(x+2))=\deg(xp(x+1))=\deg(p(x+1))+1$, absurd.